# How can I decrease PDF's margin while printing?

Tags: print-design, pdf, margin

I have an e-book (for A4 size-portrait) with border and margin of about 2 cm. Since the fonts are a bit big, I want to print two pages on same side of A4 paper (in landscape) and zoom a bit by decreasing the margin. 2 cm of margin on a side while printing a page on one side means 4 cm of margin on the middle and 2 cm on the each left and right side when two pages are printed in same side before scaling (though after scaling there is no four cm margin in the middle but you can see the ratio is same) and that would awful waste of space in the middle. Can I also decrease margin only on left and leave as it is on right so I can bind it?

Comment: I think you need to complelty edit your file accordingly.

Comment: What software are you using? Have you tried the "multiple pages per sheet" options in Adobe Acrobat or Reader to see if the desired effect can be achieved that way?

Comment: what form is the e-book in? is it a fixed-format epub3 file?

Comment: An answer can be found here: http://superuser.com/questions/956078/how-can-i-decrease-pdfs-margine-while-printing/956369#956369

Comment: @Rafael the ebook is about 2000 pages and I am looking for some automated editing option instead of editing every pages one by one.

Comment: @Scribblemacher I had tried multiple pages per sheet but the margins are too big and it would be great if I could reduce margins and zoom the content.

Comment: @maxwell it is in PDF.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do this for a PDF that you don't have the source files to (and presumably didn't create). If that's the case (and @MaxWyss linked answer didn't work), superuser is probably a more appropriate place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Open your PDF in Adobe Acrobat, select Tools -> Pages -> Crop
Then draw a rectangle around the content you want to keep
Then double-click that rectangle

[image: Acrobat Set Page Boxes dialog box]

Use this dialog to trim the white margins of your pages, then retrying printing.